# Calling Array.reduce on an array with a single element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Calling reduce on an empty array throws `TypeError` which is perfectly understandable and helps catching bugs. But when I call it on an array with a single item inside, the behavior confuses me:

```
var arr = ["a"];
arr.reduce(function(a,b){
   return [a,b]
}); //returns "a"
```

I know that reduce is not meant to be used on such an array, but I find that returning just the element without invoking the callback or throwing an error is at least strange.

Furthermore, the MDN documentation states that the callback is a "Function to execute on each value in the array, taking four arguments:".

Can someone explain the reasoning behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The callback is supposed to be a "binary function" (i.e. one that takes two arguments to operate on, plus the additional two arguments that hold the `currentIndex` and the original `array`).

If only one element is supplied, you would be passing an undefined value to the callback for either `currentValue` or `previousValue`, potentially causing runtime errors.

The design therefore assumes that given only one value (whether that be an empty array, and an `initialValue`, or an array with one value and no `initialValue`) it's better not to invoke the callback at all.

Comment: Preventing runtime error makes perfectly sense.. thanks.
Honestly I would have thrown an error for both 0 and 1 item arrays.. maybe i should implement my own reduce function
Thank you again :)

Comment: just stumbled about this. To make sure, that the callback is always invoked you would pass the `initialValue`. The signature is `arr.reduce(cb, initialValue)`. You can even pass `null`. That will work, too.

Comment: @Fuzzyma no, that's not guaranteed to work, and is bad advice.  It depends on what the `cb` does with that `null` initial value.

Comment: @Alnirak: I found that passing no initial value when using an array of only one element, the cb is not invoked at all. However - passing a different value than undefined leads to invocation of the callback

Comment: @Fuzzyma right, it'll invoke the callback, but that callback will then receive `null` as the first of its two parameters, which means the callback has to be written to expect that.

Comment: That's correct. Well you should expect to get null when you pass null. I thought that would be clear. But I guess it's better to have this hear in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Fuzzyma, Thank you  this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

reduce needs to have more than one value to accumulate, you can add a check before

```
if(arr.length <= 1 ) values = arr[0]??[]
else {
    values = arr.reduce( (a, b) => {
        return [a,b]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `reduce` on an array with a single-valued array, it will return the only element in the array because there is no other value to compare, thus the callback function won't be executed.

If you want to execute the callback function even with a single-valued array, then provide an initial value to the reducer as the second argument.

```js
var arr = ['a'];
var initialValue = 'x';

arr.reduce((a,b) => /some operation/, initialValue);
```