# Unable to find all modes in a tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to solve the following algorithms problem:

> Given a binary search tree (BST) with duplicates, find all the mode(s) (the most frequently occurred element) in the given BST.
>   Assume a BST is defined as follows:
>   The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than or equal to the node's key.
>   The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than or equal to the node's key.
>   Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.
>
> For example:
>   Given BST [1,null,2,2],
>
> ```
>    1
>     \
>      2
>     /
>    2
> ```
>
> return [2].
>
> Note: If a tree has more than one mode, you can return them in any order.
>   Follow up: Could you do that without using any extra space? (Assume that the implicit stack space incurred due to recursion does not count).

I have written the following code, but the last test case does not pass:

```
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val, left, right) {
        this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
        this.left = (left === undefined ? null : left)
        this.right = (right === undefined ? null : right)
    }
}
//updated code, doesn't seem to work, not sure if I am editing it the way it is suggested.
const findMode = root => {
    if (!root) return []
    if (root && !root.left && !root.right) return [root.val]
    const hash = {}
    let current = root
    let result = []
    let keys

    const dfs = c => {
        if (!c) return
        if (c.left) dfs(c.left)
        hash[c.val] = (hash[c.val] || 0) + 1
        if (c.right) dfs(c.right)
    }
    dfs(current)
    // keys = Object.keys(hash)
    // if (keys.length <= 1) return [+keys]
    // else keys.reduce((a, b) => {
    //     if (hash[a] === hash[b]) result.push(+a, +b)
    //     else if (hash[a] > hash[b]) {
    //         result.push(+a)
    //     } else result.push(+b)
    // })
    // return result
    keys = Object.keys(hash);
    keys.sort((a, b) => hash[b] - hash[a]);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        if (hash[key] === keys[0]) result.push(key);
    })
    return result
}
```

Here are the test cases:

```
const tree = new TreeNode(1, null, new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(2)))
console.log(findMode(tree)) //[2]

const tree2 = new TreeNode(1, null, new TreeNode(2))
console.log(findMode(tree2)) //[1,2]

const tree3 = new TreeNode(2147483647)
console.log(findMode(tree3)) //[2147483647]

const tree4 = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(1))
console.log(findMode(tree4)) // should be [1], but is []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What should be returned if all the (distinct) elements occur equal number of times, e.g. `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`?

Comment: it should return all modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `const tree4 = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(1))` your hash has only one key and `reduce` doesn't make sense on a single element array. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900182/calling-array-reduce-on-an-array-with-a-single-element-in-javascript).

In the case of single element array , you may do something like below:

`if ( Object.keys(hash).length <= 1 ) return Object.keys(hash)`

I don't think `reduce` is the right thing to do here. You need to sort the keys by their values in decreasing order and take the highest keys as below:

```
var keys = Object.keys(hash);
keys.sort((a,b) => hash[b]-hash[a]);
keys.forEach( key => {
    if ( hash[key] === hash[keys[0]] ) result.push(key);
})
return result
```

Comment: this solves the last test case, but other test cases weren't solved, so my logic is wrong for other cases such as [6,2,8,0,4,7,9,null,null,2,6], my output is [2,4,6,7,8,9] it should be [6,2]

Comment: I am not sure if I am editing it as the way you suggested, but now the code doesn't seem to work properly.  I edited it in the question for you to have a look.

Comment: @Altaf, it shouldn't be `if ( hash[key] === keys[0] ) ` but it should be `if ( hash[key] === hash[keys[0]] )`. Edited the answer.

Comment: Wow, it works! However, I am still trying to figure out how you came up with it.  Just to learn how to tackle these problems in the future.  What were the questions you asked yourself to come up with the solution?  How did you break down the problem?

Comment: Your approach was right, only thing is you selected reduce to get the result but reduce does it differently than what you think. All you need is keys that are at the top so you need to sort and get them.