# Not able to iterate through array using Reduce

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array structure that i get from the api end that looks like as given below in the,for demo purpose I have one data in array it can be multiple as well

```
mails: [,…]
0: {name: "swarup", email: "dhs.sds@xte.com", emailTwo: "", phoneOne: null, phoneTwo: "",…}
```

so now when I try to work on this array using a reduce function as below

```
try{
      mails.reduce((a,b)=>{
        console.log(a)
        return a;
    });
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }

console.log(mails[0])
```

the code inside the reduce is not executed,where I'm going wrong in this ,is there some issue with the structure,or I'm missing something in reduce I will be working the array values and return a single value

Comment: This will throw an error if `mails` is an empty array. If `mails` has a single element, it won't execute the callback.

Comment: on what basis you want to perform reduction

Comment: [Calling Array.reduce on an array with a single element in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900182)

Comment: Seems like you want a `forEach` rather than a reduce